# Bad reading from file (0 or "" values readed)

Tags: c++, string, file, constructor, stream

This is the definition of my class:

```
class BPP
{
    unsigned            n;                  /* nº de instancias */
    vector<string>      nombre_instancia;   /* nombre de la instancia*/
    vector<unsigned>    n_objetos;          /* nº de objetos a almacenar en cada instancia */
    vector<unsigned>    C;          /* capacidad máxima de cada contenedor */
    vector<unsigned>    mejor;              /* mejor nº mínimo de contenedores usados (m*) */
    vector< vector<unsigned> > tam_objeto;
```

That's my complete constructor:

```
BPP :: BPP(char fich1[])
{
    ifstream file1; string str; unsigned a, b, c, d;
    file1.open(fich1);
    if (file1.is_open()){ 
        file1 >> (unsigned &) n;
        for (unsigned k = 0 ; k < n ; ++k){
            getline(file1, str); nombre_instancia.push_back(str);
            file1 >> a; n_objetos.push_back(a);
            file1 >> b; C.push_back(b);
            file1 >> c; mejor.push_back(c);
            for (unsigned h = 0 ; h < a ; ++h){
                file1 >> d; tam_objeto[k].push_back(d);
            }
        }
    }
    file1.close();
}
```

The 5 first lines in fich1 are:

```
10
 P_0 /*Notice the space in the beginning of the line, and in the end*/
150 120 52
30
34
```

And the output is all values readed are 0 (if unsigned) or "" (if string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the new-line character after the `10` is *not* consumed by:

```
file1 >> (unsigned &) n; // Why the cast here?
```

this means that the `getline(file1, str)` call reads the new-line character only, an empty line. The next input operation is:

```
file1 >> a;
```

which fails because `P_0` is not a valid `unsigned int`. This failure prevents any further reads from the `file1` stream (its [failbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) is set).
To resolve, you could just simply call `getline()` twice, ignoring the result of the first call.

Check the result of all reads to detect failure. Doing so would have alerted you to the read failures.

Comment: I've dont what you said but still don't work. The twice calling getline() results in a segmentation fault even ignorint it result (dont store in a variable)

Comment: @freinn, you to pass a variable into `getline()`, but just ignore its value afterwards.

Comment: I've done it: `getline(file1, str);
            getline(file1, str); nombre_instancia.push_back(str);`

Comment: @freinn, I just double-checked and this is a solution to one problem. Check the result of the reads to locate when a failure occurs: `if (file1 >> a) { // ok } else { // not ok }`

Comment: Is there a way to just ignore the first space and read the line in one step?? Now it works, I've done `getline(file1, str, '\n');
            getline(file1, str, '\n');`

Comment: @freinn, after reading the line you could just erase the first character if is a space: `if (str.length() > 0 && ' ' == str[0]) str.erase(str.begin());`

Comment: OK. But why I have to do getline 2 times?? the first time it reads a space and stops reading, why??

Comment: @freinn, because the first `getline()` reads the `\n` left after the first `unsigned int` is read (I mentioned this in my answer). Note the third argument of `getline()` defaults to the new-line character so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18467/discussion-between-freinn-and-hmjd)